# Отключить жесты на win планшете

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10

Программа на WPF C#, пишу для планшета windows 10 home.
Необходимо, чтобы пользователь не смог выйти из этой программы, т.е. отключить жесты.

Comment: Чтобы ёжики плакали, давились, но продолжали юзать вашу программу, потому что не могут выйти?

Comment: Вы хотите поступить как злой управдом, который вырубает электричество всему многоквартирному дому из-за одного должника. Для этого выключают не жесты, а обрабатывают событие `Closing` у приложения, которое вы пишете.

Comment: Не совсем, хочу чтобы планшет лежал и показывал статистику и чтобы злые пользователи не смогли закрыть приложение, и чтобы не стали играть в сапера :)

Comment: @Buslon Closing - это хорошо, но не решит проблему с переключение приложения на другое.

Comment: Тогда, то что вы желаете получить реализуется специальной версией винды [Windows Embedded](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Embedded), которая используется в платежных терминалах, банкоматах, инфор.панелях и проч.

Comment: Спасибо, буду смотреть в этом направлении